# How to get the target url in my project?

Tags: java, url, uri

I have a java webproject with tomcat, java, jsp, servlet. When I run the project, I call the the webproject with an url like this for example.

```
   http://localhost:8080//root/project?action=newedit&projectname=Projekt01&Priority=low
```

Now if I submit this url in the browser and my webserver(tomcat is running of course) I get the target url which show me the projectresult-site

and the url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080//root//projectresultlist?action=projectsearch&projectid=1
```

---

Now I have another project (only Java Project and not webproject) which I call this url:

```
link = new java.net.URI("http://localhost:8080//root/project?action=newedit&projectname=Projekt01&Priority=low");
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(link);
```

The result is that the project is created well.

But now I want to have the target url, because in the target url I have the projectid that i need:

```
http://localhost:8080//root//projectresultlist?action=projectsearch&projectid=1
```

I don't know how to get the target url in my java project?

Comment: the general url for a project if you're looking to get it in a browser is localhost:8080/progject_name for example I have a project called 'pm' and I access mine via localhost:80080/pm whenever I have mine deployed

Comment: @gcalex5 that could vary if you change the port number that the application server listens. I usually do this for testing purposes having both GlassFish and JBoss running in my pc.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza nice catch I didn't think of that at the time!